# change suffixIcon color on focus Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

I am trying to make a login ui in flutter. I have a `suffixicon` decoration in `TextFormField`. I need to set it's color then change it later when the `TextFormField` is in a **focused state**

I tried giving color to the icon, but it stays constant,
I also tried with theme, but since i am new i got lost.

[dartpad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3aa88e8cad3e3d7314da6693da4d7856&null_safety=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Color suffixColor = Colors.grey;

    Focus(
            onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
              setState(() {
                (hasFocus)
                    ? suffixColor = Colors.red
                    : suffixColor = Colors.grey;
              });
            },
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.monetization_on,
                  color: suffixColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: How can i only change the `suffixIcon` color?

Comment: The code I gave you changes only the suffixIcon color...

Answer (score 2):

use focus property of TextFormField to achieve your result

```
FocusNode focus = FocusNode();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return TextFormField(
      focusNode: focus,
      onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);
      },
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: focus.hasFocus ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Great answer. In my case the line `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);` in onTap() wasn't necessary.